# UIImage display differently when saving and loading from file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm download jpeg picture from web server and load it to UIImage.

If I display the UIImage in UIImageView directly, I see the picture correctly.

But if i cache the image to file with :
     [UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image,1.0f) writeToFile:sFilePath atoimcally:YES]
    and load it with :

```
image=[UIImage imageWithContentsOFile:sFilePath]

and display this in the same UIImageView, I can see white stripes in the sides of the picture.
```

again, Exactly the same UIImageView object with the same properties settings in it.

Why is that?

Comment: You should try loading the image file using an image editor after you've cached to file to see if the stripes are being introduced in the writing step or when you are reading it back in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply write to a file the `NSData` you have loaded from the web, without going through the `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` routine.

```
[dataObject writeToURL:fileURL atomically:YES];
```

and to retrieve

```
UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[fileURL path]];
```

That works really well in my app.